# What condition am I missing in order for detail lines to match header lines

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, for-xml, for-xml-path

the following query ;

```
   DECLARE  @uname VARCHAR(10) = 'Dom',
        @pword VARCHAR(10) = 'Python',
        @sntype VARCHAR(1) = 'B',
        @action VARCHAR(10) = 'INSERT',
        @salesContractRef VARCHAR(10) = '',
        @auctionId NCHAR(10) = '';

SELECT
    RTRIM(@uname) AS '@uname',
    RTRIM(@pword) AS '@pword',

    (SELECT
    LandingId AS '@landingId',
        @snType AS '@snType',
        RTRIM(@action) AS '@action',
        COALESCE(@salesContractRef, '') AS '@salesContractRef',
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateOfPurchase, 112) AS '@saleDate',
        RTRIM(COALESCE(@auctionID, '')) AS '@auctionID',
        ISNULL(Logbook1 + ',', '') + ISNULL(Loogbook2 + ',', '') + ISNULL(Logbook3 + ',', '') AS '@logBookNums',
        ISNULL(LandingDecNumber1 + ',', '') + ISNULL(LandingDecNumber2 + ',', '') + ISNULL(LandingDecNumber3 + ',', '') AS '@landingDecNums',

        COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LandingDate1, 112), '') AS '@landingDate1',
        COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LandingDate2, 112), '') AS '@landingDate2',
        COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LandingDate3, 112), '') AS '@landingDate3',
        RTRIM(CountryOfLanding) AS '@countryOfLanding',
        RTRIM(PortOfLanding) AS '@portOfLanding',
        (SELECT
            LandingDetails.LandingId AS '@landingId',
            SpeciesCode AS '@speciesCode',
            RTRIM(FishingArea) AS '@faoAreaCode',
            RTRIM(IcesZone) AS '@ZoneCode'
        FROM Landings.LandingDetails
        INNER JOIN Landings.LandingHeaders lh
            ON Landings.LandingDetails.LandingId = lh.LandingId
            WHERE lh.Posted = 0


        FOR XML PATH ('detail'), TYPE)

    FROM Landings.LandingHeaders
    JOIN Landings.Vessels
        ON Landings.LandingHeaders.VesselId = Vessels.VesselId
        WHERE Posted = 0
    FOR XML PATH ('sale'), TYPE)
FOR XML PATH ('abc')
```

produces this output;

```
    <abc uname="Dom" pword="Python">
  <sale landingId="3388" snType="B" action="INSERT" salesContractRef="" saleDate="20130706" auctionID="" logBookNums="L7014  ,L7015  ,L7016  ," landingDecNums="" landingDate1="20130705" landingDate2="" landingDate3="" countryOfLanding="GBR" portOfLanding="GBHTG">
    <detail landingId="3388" speciesCode="BSS" faoAreaCode="27" ZoneCode="VIID" />
    <detail landingId="3388" speciesCode="PLE" faoAreaCode="27" ZoneCode="VIID" />
    <detail landingId="3388" speciesCode="HER" faoAreaCode="27" ZoneCode="VIID" />
    <detail landingId="3389" speciesCode="SBX" faoAreaCode="27" ZoneCode="VIID" />
    <detail landingId="3389" speciesCode="PLE" faoAreaCode="27" ZoneCode="VIID" />
    <detail landingId="3389" speciesCode="PLE" faoAreaCode="27" ZoneCode="VIID" />
  </sale>
  <sale landingId="3389" snType="B" action="INSERT" salesContractRef="" saleDate="20130706" auctionID="" logBookNums="" landingDecNums="" landingDate1="20130705" landingDate2="" landingDate3="" countryOfLanding="GBR" portOfLanding="GBHTG">
    <detail landingId="3388" speciesCode="BSS" faoAreaCode="27" ZoneCode="VIID" />
    <detail landingId="3388" speciesCode="PLE" faoAreaCode="27" ZoneCode="VIID" />
    <detail landingId="3388" speciesCode="HER" faoAreaCode="27" ZoneCode="VIID" />
    <detail landingId="3389" speciesCode="SBX" faoAreaCode="27" ZoneCode="VIID" />
    <detail landingId="3389" speciesCode="PLE" faoAreaCode="27" ZoneCode="VIID" />
    <detail landingId="3389" speciesCode="PLE" faoAreaCode="27" ZoneCode="VIID" />
  </sale>
</abc>
```

This is almost exactly as I would have hoped save for the fact that the detail lines are being duplicated for both sale lines when in reality they should only appear for their relevant sale line.  Matching the landingid's is clearly pulling out the right detail lines, just not sure what extra little tweak I'm missing.

Thanks

EDIT:  Changed the SQL Query to the following;

```
DECLARE @uname VARCHAR(10) = 'Dom',
        @pword VARCHAR(10) = 'Python',
        @sntype VARCHAR(1) = 'B',
        @action VARCHAR(10) = 'INSERT',
        @salesContractRef VARCHAR(10) = '',
        @auctionId NCHAR(10) = '';

SELECT
    RTRIM(@uname) AS '@uname',
    RTRIM(@pword) AS '@pword',

    (SELECT

        @snType AS '@snType',
        RTRIM(@action) AS '@action',
        COALESCE(@salesContractRef, '') AS '@salesContractRef',
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateOfPurchase, 112) AS '@saleDate',
        RTRIM(COALESCE(@auctionID, '')) AS '@auctionID',
        ISNULL(Logbook1 + ',', '') + ISNULL(Loogbook2 + ',', '') + ISNULL(Logbook3 + ',', '') AS '@logBookNums',
        ISNULL(LandingDecNumber1 + ',', '') + ISNULL(LandingDecNumber2 + ',', '') + ISNULL(LandingDecNumber3 + ',', '') AS '@landingDecNums',

        COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LandingDate1, 112), '') AS '@landingDate1',
        COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LandingDate2, 112), '') AS '@landingDate2',
        COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LandingDate3, 112), '') AS '@landingDate3',
        RTRIM(CountryOfLanding) AS '@countryOfLanding',
        RTRIM(PortOfLanding) AS '@portOfLanding',
        (SELECT

            SpeciesCode AS '@speciesCode',
            RTRIM(FishingArea) AS '@faoAreaCode',
            RTRIM(IcesZone) AS '@ZoneCode'


        FOR XML PATH ('detail'), TYPE)

    FROM Landings.LandingHeaders

    INNER JOIN Landings.LandingDetails ld
        ON Landings.LandingHeaders.LandingId = ld.LandingId

    WHERE Posted = 0

    FOR XML PATH ('sale'), TYPE)
FOR XML PATH ('abc')
```

which now produces the following output;

```
    <abc uname="Dom" pword="Python">
  <sale snType="B" action="INSERT" salesContractRef="" saleDate="20130706" auctionID="" logBookNums="L7014  ,L7015  ,L7016  ," landingDecNums="" landingDate1="20130705" landingDate2="" landingDate3="" countryOfLanding="GBR" portOfLanding="GBHTG">
    <detail speciesCode="BSS" faoAreaCode="27" ZoneCode="VIID" />
  </sale>
  <sale snType="B" action="INSERT" salesContractRef="" saleDate="20130706" auctionID="" logBookNums="L7014  ,L7015  ,L7016  ," landingDecNums="" landingDate1="20130705" landingDate2="" landingDate3="" countryOfLanding="GBR" portOfLanding="GBHTG">
    <detail speciesCode="PLE" faoAreaCode="27" ZoneCode="VIID" />
  </sale>
  <sale snType="B" action="INSERT" salesContractRef="" saleDate="20130706" auctionID="" logBookNums="L7014  ,L7015  ,L7016  ," landingDecNums="" landingDate1="20130705" landingDate2="" landingDate3="" countryOfLanding="GBR" portOfLanding="GBHTG">
    <detail speciesCode="HER" faoAreaCode="27" ZoneCode="VIID" />
  </sale>
  <sale snType="B" action="INSERT" salesContractRef="" saleDate="20130706" auctionID="" logBookNums="" landingDecNums="" landingDate1="20130705" landingDate2="" landingDate3="" countryOfLanding="GBR" portOfLanding="GBHTG">
    <detail speciesCode="SBX" faoAreaCode="27" ZoneCode="VIID" />
  </sale>
  <sale snType="B" action="INSERT" salesContractRef="" saleDate="20130706" auctionID="" logBookNums="" landingDecNums="" landingDate1="20130705" landingDate2="" landingDate3="" countryOfLanding="GBR" portOfLanding="GBHTG">
    <detail speciesCode="PLE" faoAreaCode="27" ZoneCode="VIID" />
  </sale>
  <sale snType="B" action="INSERT" salesContractRef="" saleDate="20130706" auctionID="" logBookNums="" landingDecNums="" landingDate1="20130705" landingDate2="" landingDate3="" countryOfLanding="GBR" portOfLanding="GBHTG">
    <detail speciesCode="PLE" faoAreaCode="27" ZoneCode="VIID" />
  </sale>
</abc>
```

At least the detail lines now match the sale lines, but it's producing a separate sale line for each detail line.  There's clearly one small bit missing.  I have tried a Group By LandingHeaders.LandingId but that seems to cause more problems.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: It's for ms sql 2012

Answer (score 0):

I think this

```
WHERE lh.Posted = 0
```

Should be replaced with this

```
WHERE lh.Posted = 0 AND lh.LandingId=LandingId
```

If it complains that LandingId is ambiguous then add alias for `FROM Landings.LandingHeaders` so it will be smth like `FROM Landings.LandingHeaders lh1` and then try

```
WHERE lh.Posted = 0 AND lh.LandingId=lh1.LandingId
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it still produces the same result.